# similar function for http_post_fields?

Tags: php, pecl

is there a similar function for http_post_fields from pecl_http? my current host only installs extensions from http://pear.php.net/ (not sure why, but i don't have ssh access but rather a web gui, and can only install extensions that are avai. from there)

here is my code

```
<?php
    $files = array(
        array(
            'name' => 'torrent',            // Don't change
            'type' => 'application/x-bittorrent',
            'file' => '0-273-70244-0.pdf.torrent'           // Full path for file to upload
        )
    );

    $http_resp = http_post_fields( 'http://torcache.net/autoupload.php', array(), $files );
    $tmp = explode( "\r\n", $http_resp );
    $infoHash = substr( $tmp[count( $tmp ) - 1], 0, 40 );
    var_dump($infoHash);
    unset( $tmp, $http_resp, $files );
```

currently this doesn't work as im getting an undefined function for http_post_fields

Comment: PEAR is not extensions, it is just a php libraries you may download yourself. As any other `.php` files all you need is just to include them as you do with another `.php` files

Comment: @zerkms PECL_HTTP is the extension that i need so i cannot include it, http://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http,  my host only allows extensions from the PEAR library and PECL_HTTP is not in this library, so i need an similar extension that has same functions as PECL_HTTP from PEAR library

Comment: "my host only allows extensions from the PEAR library" --- PEAR **is not** php extensions, and in fact they needn't to be "installed" like PECL should. PEAR - is just a repository of php libraries, that you can copy and distribute with your project without your provider assistance

Comment: @zerkms Good Sir I am not sure what you mean, my understanding is that PEAR is a library, but I need to install this extension called PECL_HTTP which i cannot find when i search http://pear.php.net;

Comment: I understand that. I just say that PEAR is not an extension and you don't need hosting provider assistance to use PEAR. PS: about the answer - you can send post in million ways. curl, sockets are the most obvious and accessible, without exotic `pecl_http` extensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To upload torrents to torcache I just use:

```
<?php
$upload_result = curl_upload('http://torcache.net/autoupload.php','torrent','/absoulte_full_path_to_torrent/torrent.torrent');

function curl_upload($url,$fileFormAttribute,$file){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        $post = array($fileFormAttribute=>"@".$file);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        return $response;
}
?>
```

`$upload_result` will contain the torrent hash if success, it will fail if its not the absolute path to the torrent.

Comment: I get a blank webpage when using this, i tried var_dump $upload_result and i get bool(false) returned

Answer (score 4):

There are a bunch of ways to post data from PHP, here are a couple to get you started:

**Streams**

Use a [stream context](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) to open (with [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)) a URL with the post data you want to send

```php
function do_post($url, $data)
{
  $params = array('http' => array(
              'method' => 'POST',
              'content' => $data
            ));

  $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
  $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
  if (!$fp) {
    throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
  if ($response === false) {
    throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  return $response;
}
```

Code sample adapted from [Wez Furlong](http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl/).

**CURL**

To use [CURL](http://www.php.net/curl) the PHP extension will need to be available, this is more common than not these days but depends on your host.

```php
function do_post($url, $data)
{
  $ch = curl_init($url);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $response;
}
```

Code sample adapted from [Lorna Jane](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2010/three-ways-to-make-a-post-request-from-php).

Comment: This line:
`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`
should be:
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`